# Changing the color by moving mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all I'm not good at english sorry for that.

My problem is in else of js file.
i want to change the color of h1 tag when the xposition is on it and any letter that is before of the xposition must be changed to white.

```js
var object = document.getElementById('object'); 
var box = document.getElementById('box'); 
var h1 = document.querySelector('#box > h1'); 
box.addEventListener('mousemove', moveObject); 

function moveObject(event) { 
   var xPosition = event.clientX - box.getBoundingClientRect().left; 
   xPosition = Math.max(0, Math.min(xPosition, box.clientWidth)); 
   object.style.width = xPosition + 'px'; 

   var h1Left = h1.getBoundingClientRect().left - box.getBoundingClientRect().left; 
   var h1Right = h1Left + h1.clientWidth; 

   if (xPosition < h1Left) { 
       h1.style.color = 'black'; 
   } 
   else if (xPosition > h1Right) { 
       h1.style.color = 'white'; 
   } 
   else { 
       var distanceToH1Left = xPosition - h1Left; 
       var percentage = distanceToH1Left / h1.clientWidth; 
       var red = Math.round(255 * percentage); 
       var green = Math.round(255 * percentage); 
       var blue = Math.round(255 * percentage); 
       h1.style.color = 'rgb(' + red + ',' + green + ',' + blue + ')'; 
   } 
}
```

```css
#box { 
   display: flex; 
   justify-content: center; 
   align-items: center; 
   background-color: #F84F39; 
   width: 100%; 
   height: 100vh; 
   position: relative; 
   overflow: hidden; 
}
 
 #object { 
   position: absolute; 
   height: 100%; 
   background-color: #1B1A27; 
   left: 0; 
}

 #box > h1 { 
   font-family: 'Verdana', 'Geneva', 'Tahoma', sans-serif; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   position: relative; 
   z-index: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div id="box"> 
   <h1>The power of Gods</h1> 
   <div id="object"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: How is superlist related?

Comment: take a look at its header and hover it with mouse and also look how the color of header tag changes

Comment: Please edit your question and describe the problem or error you've encountered with your JS code. So far, we just have  your requirements and your code, with no question or explanation of what the problem is.

Comment: my problem is in the else of the js code. look into that link that I provide at the bottom of my question to get the idea. the letters should be changing their colors one by one

Comment: Too hard to debug. too complicated, and the code is all minified.  can you reproduce it using a simple codepen, etc?  Or, at least add some "console.log" inside the `moveObject`  that prints all the variables.

Comment: Does anyone still has access to this question? please help me

Comment: @sp3ctre from the site you linked they seem to be having two overlapping divs/h1  and not a color transition that you are making

Comment: @deepanshu223 what should I do? can you give the codes of that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this by just having two differently styled copies of the same thing stacked on top of each other, then reveal it as you move the mouse moves.

This is not perfect, I had to remove the flexbox stuff and the text centering since when you modify the width that would also modify where the center is. So this is not perfect, but a good start possibly

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('box-wrapper');
const box = document.getElementById('box-reveal');
wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', moveObject); 

function moveObject(event) { 
   let xPosition = event.clientX - box.getBoundingClientRect().left;
   //xPosition = Math.max(0, Math.min(xPosition, box.clientWidth)); 
   box.style.width = xPosition + 'px'; 
}
```

```css
#box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {

  background-color: #F84F39; 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh;
}

.box > h1 { 
  font-family: 'Verdana', 'Geneva', 'Tahoma', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  
  z-index: 1; 
}
 
#box-reveal { 
   background-color: #1B1A27;
}

#box-reveal > h1 {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>The power of Gods</h1> 
  </div>

  <div class="box" id="box-reveal">
    <h1>The power of Gods</h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Attempt #2 - using `clip: rect()` and then setting that value seems to work well for the reasons the above did not!

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('box-wrapper');
const box = document.getElementById('box-reveal');
wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', moveObject); 

function moveObject(event) { 
   let xPosition = event.clientX - box.getBoundingClientRect().left;
   //xPosition = Math.max(0, Math.min(xPosition, box.clientWidth)); 
   box.style.clip = `rect(0, ${xPosition}px, 100vh, 0)`;
}
```

```css
#box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #F84F39; 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh;
}

.box > h1 { 
  font-family: 'Verdana', 'Geneva', 'Tahoma', sans-serif; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  
  z-index: 1; 
}
 
#box-reveal { 
   background-color: #1B1A27;
}

#box-reveal > h1 {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>The power of Gods</h1> 
  </div>

  <div class="box" id="box-reveal">
    <h1>The power of Gods</h1> 
  </div>
</div>
```